# Get div data from Get request

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

i have a little question, i made a Get request using axios to my React app to a website and i get the html response : responseData.data .
But now i want to get the content of a specific div inside of the responseData.data.
For example this one :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="devise-layout-html">
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">  
    </head>

    <body class="ui_charcoal login-page application navless" data-page="sessions:new">

    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="active login-box tab-pane" id="ldapmain" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="login-body">
    <form id="new_ldap_user" class="gl-show-field-errors" action="/users/auth/ldapmain/callback" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="V8qeuk9QAYk51gorLAobEYGvCMMuyPpuUKXAwtBm2Zw1b1/7BVibiPhRWI7aVrQBa2p+CkKLGCEbQV/UIxZmkA==" /><div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">LDAP Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control top" title="This field is required." autofocus="autofocus" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control bottom" title="This field is required." required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="remember-me checkbox">
    <label for="remember_me">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" value="1" />
    <span>Remember me</span>
    </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign in" class="btn-save btn" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And i want to acess to this data : `<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="V8qeuk9QAYk51gorLAobEYGvCMMuyPpuUKXAwtBm2Zw1b1/7BVibiPhRWI7aVrQBa2p+CkKLGCEbQV/UIxZmkA==" />`(the value). Is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: i precise that getElementById doesn't work in my case

Comment: I really don't think its a good idea to download all the html if you want just to get specific information from html. You should parse the data on server side and return only required information.

Comment: i can't retrieve this specific info from the server.. That's the only way

Comment: So thats make a difference :)  You can use regex expression for that, look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can also try to parse it as an XML. using for example this [xml parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-parser)</strike>

EDIT:

In your case the fastest way to get the value from specific tag attribute is to use regex expression: For example

```
/(<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token")((.|\s|\v)*?)(\/>)/
```

will allow you to extract the `value` attribute from input

```js
const htmlDocumentString = '...<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="V8qeuk9QAYk51gorLAobEYGvCMMuyPpuUKXAwtBm2Zw1b1/7BVibiPhRWI7aVrQBa2p+CkKLGCEbQV/UIxZmkA==" />...'


const reg = /(<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token")((.|\s|\v)*?)(\/>)/

// The second group of regex match should contain value="..."
const vAttr = reg.exec(htmlDocumentString)[2]

// Time to extract content of the value attribute. 
// The fastest way by using substring and character indexes like so
const value = vAttr.substring(vAttr.indexOf('"') + 1, vAttr.lastIndexOf('"'))

console.log(value) // [string] "V8qeuk9QAYk51gorLAob..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). Like jQuery but designed for the server.